# How to tell if my iPad and iOS Simulator are using the same iCloud account?

Tags: ios-simulator, icloud, xcode6.1, osx-yosemite

I am trying to sync my iPad with the iOS simulator (8.1.1) for debugging under XCode 6.1.  How can I tell if they are both using the same iCloud account?  I have looked in Google and SO, but found nothing that would answer my question.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the Settings app, and scroll down to iCloud.  It lists your account below "iCloud"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uhhh... there is no "settings" app... the iPad and the iMac are under different operating systems, therefore have different ways of determining the settings... can you be more specific about each of the OS?

Comment: You said nothing about OSX in your question.  Your question was about the iOS Simulator and iPad device.  My answer is correct for the question asked.

Comment: 1.  there is NO "settings" app
2.  the simulator runs on OSX and simulates iOS; I don't see where you set the iCloud account on the simulator

Comment: You run the Settings app running on your simulated device within the iOS Simulator.  See the screenshots that I added.

Comment: Never knew there was a settings app on the simulator...thank you for informing me... I appreciate your time... SD